# Divisors inside an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops

I need to write a method that takes an array of integers and checks for every element if all its divisors (except the number itself and 1) are present in this array. If yes, the method will return true.

For example, the following array will return true:

```
4,5,10,2
```

I can't think of something efficient enough to be implemented. Could you guys help me out here?

I've been thinking to iterate through every element in the array, search for all of its divisors, put them on array, return the array and then compare to the elements in the original array.

This is a possible solution and it could work but I want to know of other possible solutions.

EDIT: Here is a code I've came up with but it is super slow. Could you guys help me optimise it a little bit?:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Divisors {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                int[] numbers = { 4, 5, 10, 2 };
                boolean flag = true;
                for (int num : numbers) {
                        if (num % 2 != 0) {
                                for (int subNum = 1; subNum < num / 2; num += 2) {
                                        if(num%subNum == 0 && subNum != 1) {
                                                if(!Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(subNum)) {
                                                        flag = false;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        } else {
                                for (int subNum = 1; subNum < num / 2; num++) {
                                        if(num%subNum == 0 && subNum != 1) {
                                                if(!Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(subNum)) {
                                                        flag = false;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }

                System.out.println("Result is: "+flag);
        }
}
```

Comment: "I can't think of something efficient enough to be implemented. Could you guys help me out here?" Start with something inefficient, share the code on code review and they'll help you make it better. If you do have something that you've tried, and it doesn't work, share that code here and the error you're getting.

Comment: Put all elements in a `TreeSet<Integer>`, find all divisors of every element (optionally put them in a `Set`, too), check presence. Sets have good lookup / intersection performance.

Comment: @9000 this takes too much time as well =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: well, before an optimization target is even _defined_, it's hard to tell how to make the code (what code?) more efficient. Profile first, optimize later. If you only process very short arrays of small integers, cache coherence may make array scanning way more efficient than fumbling with trees. If your numbers rarely ever repeat, sorting and binary search is better. To say nothing about caching the primes used for factorization. The question is, admittedly, rather too vague for a proper answer.

Comment: Ok I added to this post a code I came up with. It's pretty slow so definitely it needs optimisation. Could you guys have a look?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following alogorithm solves your need. I have tested it on a few cases and it seems to work.
For example the array:

```
int[] set = {2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 15, 18, 35};
```

executes instantly giving the answer "true". Try removing the 7 which will give the answer "false".

You call it thus:

```
reduce(set, 0, 0)
```

The principle used is to iterative recursively through the array, reducing the array through factorization of the array by each element. If you find an element which is smaller than the last factor, it means it can't be factored. This only works if the array is sorted. Once you reach the end of the array, you know all elements have been factored.

```
private static boolean reduce (int[] set, int index, int factor) {
    // NOTE: set must be a sorted set of integers
    if (index == set.length) {
        return true;
    } else {
        int divisor = set[index];
        if (divisor != 1) {
            if (divisor < factor) return false;
            for (int i = index; i < set.length; i++) {
                while ((set[i]%divisor) == 0) {
                set[i] = set[i]/divisor;
                }
            }
            return reduce(set, index+1, divisor);
        } else {
            return reduce(set, index+1, factor);
        }

    }
}
```

See if it works, let me know if you run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

1.Iterate through every element in the array
2. Find in for loop its divisor
3. While doing 2), check for every divisor if it is contained in the array. If false - return false.

Comment: I tried to do what you advised and it works but the code is super slow( it takes it 5 seconds to determine true or false for an array with just 4 elements). I added it to the post. Could you please take a look?